# Angular inside Apache HTTPS

Tags: angular, apache, https

I have an App in Angular 4 that I built with ng build --prod command, this files are in the Apache folder and working good but when I refresh the page or I try to access for example *192.168.1.10/login*, I get this error:

> **Not Found** The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

I know that this error is because Apache try to resolve the directory throw the folders but I setup it and it dosen't still working:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  my-app

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Observation**:

Before to implements HTTPS I have this configuration and working fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `https` works through port `*:443` and your config is for port `*:80`

Try duplicating your config for `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: I tried with the same config but changing the 80 port to 443 port and I'm getting a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: I used this instruction in the routing.ts file:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

Works fine.